# Are automatrons counted as "companions" by "Lone Wanderer" perk?

Tags: fallout-4

So, in Fallout 4 we have the perk "Lone Wanderer", which applies a lot of useful buffs to a character, if he is not accompanied by a companion. And in "Automatron" DLC, we have ability to create custom robots, which follow us and do stuff.

So, my question is - are those robots counted as companions, and will they cease the effect of "Lone Wanderer"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They count as 'Real' companions, so Lone Wanderer is not compatible. Inspirational is.

The only companions that do not eliminate Lone Wanderer are quest-based temporary followers and the Dog.

I confirmed this myself, in-game.

Comment: I think this is probably true. Did you test it yourself, or have something to cite?

Comment: @DCShannon I asked a modder friend, and confirmed in-game.